# generate a self signed certificate in docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I need to generate a self signed certificate when the docker starts . 
basically our docker is started using concourse ci . So it has to be in the dockerfile and cannot use any options using docker run .

Let me know any inputs for this

Answer (score 38):

What is wrong with simple `RUN` command? It works for me and the self-signed certificate is created successfully.

```
FROM debian:wheezy

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y openssl && \
    openssl genrsa -des3 -passout pass:x -out server.pass.key 2048 && \
    openssl rsa -passin pass:x -in server.pass.key -out server.key && \
    rm server.pass.key && \
    openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr \
        -subj "/C=UK/ST=Warwickshire/L=Leamington/O=OrgName/OU=IT Department/CN=example.com" && \
    openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in server.csr -signkey server.key -out server.crt
```

Once in `Dockerfile`, the certificate is created only once during the image build; then you have the certificate available in the image.

If you need a new self-signed certificate each time a container starts, it's possible with the use of an external shell script. Like so:

```
#!/bin/bash

openssl genrsa -des3 -passout pass:x -out server.pass.key 2048
openssl rsa -passin pass:x -in server.pass.key -out server.key
rm server.pass.key
openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr \
    -subj "/C=UK/ST=Warwickshire/L=Leamington/O=OrgName/OU=IT Department/CN=example.com"
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in server.csr -signkey server.key -out server.crt
```

And then put that shell script into your `Dockerfile` and set up the default execution:

```
FROM debian:wheezy

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y openssl

COPY generate-certificate.sh /tmp/generate-certificate.sh

CMD [ "/tmp/generate-certificate.sh" ]
```

In this case each time you start a container with `docker run ....`, a new unique certificate is generated.

Comment: -passout pass:x too short https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1467669

Comment: How would you do this for Let's Encrypt certificates? Also generate them in a RUN command in Dockerfile?

Comment: @ppicom spin up nginx during build and run certbot. However generating letsencrypt certs during build doesn't make sense. They are alive only for 90 or so days, you'd have to be rebuilding the image constantly. Makes more sense to run nginx container separately from your app.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I'm still trying to figure out how to set up all the SSL show business for a services oriented application running on a Swarm :S

Comment: Using `RUN` makes the certificate AND the secret key parts of the image.  So anybody that can pull the image can impersonate you. (Obviously self-signed certs are not worth much and in most test setups clients probably "just trust them" in any case.)  Doing it in `CMD` / `ENTRYPOINT` is better by not leaking key in the image — but also means clients can't know the right cert even if they want, have to "just trust them".  But key & cert have to be generated together :-(  I suspect best approach is generate externally and pass by mounted volume / env vars?

Comment: @BeniCherniavsky-Paskin correct, if you're on a production system, you can use letsencrypt to maintain the certificates and save them to a location which you mount with a `volume` flag. Also, self-signed certs will be flagged as "unknown issuer" or something in the browser. OP was asking about self-signed, because they use it in a CI, so the security lies on the DevOps person to maintain it correctly.

Answer (score 15):

I used similar in nginx:alpine:

```
FROM nginx:1.19.1-alpine

RUN apk update && \
    apk add --no-cache openssl && \
    openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 \
    -subj  "/C=CA/ST=QC/O=Company Inc/CN=example.com" \
     -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/ssl/private/nginx-selfsigned.key \
     -out /etc/ssl/certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt;
```

Answer (score 3):

inspired by Kevin Kopf

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

OPENSSL_INSTALLED=false

if which openssl >/dev/null
then 
  OPENSSL_INSTALLED=true
fi

## certificate parameters
COUNTRY_NAME="US"
STATE_NAME="New Mexico"
LOCALITY_NAME="Roswell"
ORGANIZATION_NAME="ACME Co, LLC."
ORGANIZATIONAL_UNIT_NAME="ACME Department"
COMMON_NAME="www.domain.com"
EMAIL_ADDRESS="email@domain"

## apache or nginx
SERVER_KEY="apache-selfsigned.key"
SERVER_KEY_PATH="/etc/ssl/private"
SERVER_CRT="apache-selfsigned.crt"
SERVER_CRT_PATH="/etc/ssl/certs"

OPENSSL_SUBJ_OPTIONS="
Country Name (2 letter code) [AU]:$COUNTRY_NAME
State or Province Name (full name) [Some-State]:$STATE_NAME
Locality Name (eg, city) []:$LOCALITY_NAME
Organization Name (eg, company) [Internet Widgits Pty Ltd]:$ORGANIZATION_NAME
Organizational Unit Name (eg, section) []:$ORGANIZATIONAL_UNIT_NAME
Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name) []:$COMMON_NAME
Email Address []:$EMAIL_ADDRESS
"

if [ "$OPENSSL_INSTALLED" = true ]
then 
    echo "generating self signed certificate"
    echo "with these options: "
    echo "$OPENSSL_SUBJ_OPTIONS"
    echo ""

    ## generate self signed certificate
    openssl req \
        -new \
        -newkey rsa:4096 \
        -days 365 \
        -nodes \
        -x509 \
        -subj "/emailAddress=$EMAIL_ADDRESS/C=$COUNTRY_NAME/ST=$STATE_NAME/L=$LOCALITY_NAME/O=$ORGANIZATION_NAME/OU=$ORGANIZATIONAL_UNIT_NAME/CN=$COMMON_NAME" \
        -keyout $SERVER_KEY \
        -out $SERVER_CRT
    
    ## uncomment: move to correct location
    #mv -f $SERVER_KEY $SERVER_KEY_PATH/$SERVER_KEY
    #mv -f $SERVER_CRT $SERVER_CRT_PATH/$SERVER_CRT
else
    echo "openssl is not installed"
    exit 1
fi

#end
```